# mode.fit output when splitting stdout

Tags: ubuntu, logging, keras, stdout

I have a code using keras `model.fit()`. For each fit epoche I can see a bar of the form:

> [====================>.........]
> This bar is advancing for each epoch.

I have tried to run my code so that it splits the output to both terminal and output file using `python3 my_code.py 1>&2|tee output.log` but for some reason I get this weird unfolding of the output:

> 256/5588 [>.............................] - ETA: 16s - loss: 10.4521 - acc: 0.0820
> 512/5588 [=>............................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 9.6223 - acc: 0.0977
> 768/5588 [===>..........................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 9.1487 - acc: 0.0924
> 1024/5588 [====>.........................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 8.7696 - acc: 0.0986
> 1280/5588 [=====>........................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 8.5107 - acc: 0.1062
> 1536/5588 [=======>......................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 8.2851 - acc: 0.1159
> 1792/5588 [========>.....................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 8.1778 - acc: 0.1183
> 2048/5588 [=========>....................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 7.9324 - acc: 0.1167
> 2304/5588 [===========>..................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 7.6034 - acc: 0.1181
> 2560/5588 [============>.................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 7.2588 - acc: 0.1187
> 2816/5588 [==============>...............] - ETA: 4s - loss: 6.9440 - acc: 0.1236
> 3072/5588 [===============>..............] - ETA: 4s - loss: 6.6901 - acc: 0.1263
> 3328/5588 [================>.............] - ETA: 4s - loss: 6.4858 - acc: 0.1304
> 3584/5588 [==================>...........] - ETA: 3s - loss: 6.3391 - acc: 0.1339
> 3840/5588 [===================>..........] - ETA: 3s - loss: 6.1690 - acc: 0.1378
> 4096/5588 [====================>.........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 6.0001 - acc: 0.1399
> 4352/5588 [======================>.......] - ETA: 2s - loss: 5.8396 - acc: 0.1434
> 4608/5588 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 5.7123 - acc: 0.1469
> 4864/5588 [=========================>....] - ETA: 1s - loss: 5.5783 - acc: 0.1507
> 5120/5588 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.4661 - acc: 0.1537
> 5376/5588 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.3428 - acc: 0.1583
> 5588/5588 [==============================] - 10s 2ms/step - loss: 5.2570 - acc: 0.1605 - val_loss: 2.4897 - val_acc: 0.2377

I am aware that the loading bar is not design for a log file but I would still like to see it on the terminal while saving a full bar (not it's unfolding) to the log file. Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: This does not answer your question directly, but can you try `cat output.log` from the terminal?  You may see what you expect on the console.

Comment: @KotaMori, that indeed does not answer my question as I would like to have a continuous feedback without having to execute a `cat` operation.

Comment: Yup.  Try reading the whole logfile as a string on python.  you should see many `\x08`, which is the backspace.  These backspaces move cursor on the console, and implements the progress bar visualization.   I don't think you can change the behavior easily.  So only approach I can think of is you manipulate the text file using regex, say removing a part between two line breaks that contain backspaces,